# How to align the C# label in the style of Linux booting

Tags: c#, winforms, alignment, label

I am using Visual Studio 2015, developing winform program. I would like to have a C# label to make the item names in the left while the results aligned to right. Just like the booting information demonstration of some of Linux distributions as below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [linuxgazette.net](http://linuxgazette.net/156/misc/prestia/rc.sysinit.png))</sub>

In Console.Write(), seems the String.Format() works while in a label, seems it does not.
Is there any method to do the same thing like that?
Thanks!

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: @Dennis I am developing winform application with vs 2015. No extra UI framework.

Comment: What font are you using in your label? is it monospaced or proportional?

Comment: You'll have to make it look like a boot screen or console window, you must use a fixed-pitch font.  Like Consolas or Courier New.  Or use two columns of labels or use a ListView in Details view mode.  ListView is the sane choice.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, Yes! I got your idea and that works! Thanks for that!

Comment: When not using a fixed spaced font, and this on a winform, you need to draw your strings direct via GDI (you can measure the string you like to print and so you can center it between to brackets - which you can draw on fixed positions). DrawString, MeasureString are the functions you´ll need.

Comment: @RowlandShaw In the beginning I used the default Microsoft Sans Serif which did not work. Following the suggestion from Hans Passant, I use Courier New, and then the String.Format() works.~